# Dependencies on feature branches with Gitflow

Tags: git, workflow, git-flow

We are using Gitflow http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
as our way of working and the devs keeps on saying that they always get into the problem that the next feature builds upon the last one (adding new functionality) so i told them that they can branch off the previous feature, work locally and when the previous feature is approved (pull request) then they can rebase based on develop branch so it looks nice in the history but they don't like that so they suggest a integration branch so that all work is based on that one then they merge back to integration branch and then issue a pull request into develop branch so in this way they are always working on latest code.

What's your take on this ?

Yes i know that dependent work is not good but i don't think there is a way around it, i mean you are building feature upon previous work and if that work is not there well then you can't make it.

Also maybe our features are too big but i don't think so, we use 3-4 days per dev per branch before we usually issue a pull request.

donnib

Comment: Did you ever come to a resolution for this?